# Type parameter with nullable bounds is used inside extension function

Tags: kotlin, generics, rx-java

I'm getting a following warning and I'm not sure how to fix it:

> Type mismatch: type parameter with nullable bounds is used (T1, T2) -> R is used where ((T1, T2) -> R)! was expected. This warning will become an error soon
> Type mismatch: type parameter with nullable bounds is used R is used where R was expected. This warning will become an error soon

Function

```
inline fun <T1, T2, R> combineLatest(
observable1: Observable<T1>,
observable2: Observable<T2>,
crossinline function: (T1, T2) -> R
): Observable<R> = Observable.combineLatest(
   observable1,
   observable2,
   { T1, T2 -> function(T1, T2) }
)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Compiles without errors in Kotlin 1.4.10.
Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: What is the point of this function? It looks like it is recursively calling itself.

Comment: For me it's giving me the warning with kotlin 1.4.21 every time I clean and build. @МихаилНафталь

Comment: @Tenfour04 if you look closely it does not call itself. It calls `Observable.combineLatest` so you can call it like `combineLatest(ob1,ob2){results here}`

Comment: Tried with Kotlin 1.4.21, still no warnings. What version of rxJava do you use?

Comment: I'm on 2.1.1. Also I can only see it when I clean and then build.

Comment: Yes, managed to reproduce on 2.x. Initially I've tried with 3.0.8.
The problem is that in 2.x this method lack of `@NonNull` annotations, so Kotlin is a bit confused about arguments nullability. I believe you need to [migrate to 3.x](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-3.0). Anyway, 2.x support will be discontinued in a couple months.